# Why does voice+video recording not work with built-in mike but works with headset - Dell Vostro laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, video, audio-recording, dell-vostro

I need to do some recording of voice + video together. This is on Windows 7 using a Dell Vostro 2420 laptop.

When I try to record the video using the mike that comes with my headphones, it works (though the volume is a bit low). But when I try to record the video using the laptop's built-in mike, it does not work - the video does get recorded but no sound of me speaking is heard.

Why is this happening?

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Recording and playback devices are enumerated in Windows environments, and while Windows SHOULD select the proper device depending on the presence/status of devices, this is not always the case.

If none of the below works, you should ensure that your audio/motherboard drivers are up-to-date and functioning properly before trying again.

Try right-clicking on your volume control and selecting `Recording Devices` (or alternately bring up your start-menu and typing `manage audio devices` or `change sound card settings` in the search box to access your sound settings; go to the `Recording` tab).

[image: Accessing sound settings from the search box]

This panel should display a list of recording interfaces accessible to your system. Select the device that corresponds to your built-in microphone, and select the `Set Default` button near the bottom-right corner of the window.

[image: Set your recording device as the default.]

If you find that this has not alleviated the issue, you may need to adjust your device's properties by selecting it and clicking the `Properties` button to ensure that the device is not muted or recording at an excessively low level.

[image: Open your devices properties]
[image: Check your levels]

If the device still fails to record properly, you may try selecting the device and clicking `Configure`, then `Set up microphone` to step through a Windows wizard in order to configure the device.

[image: Configure your recording device]

The pictures and many of the instructions above are from a guide on the defunct site 7tutorials.com, now [preserved](https://web.archive.org/web/20110724053537/http://www.7tutorials.com/how-change-default-playback-recording-audio-device) on the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Will try out what you suggest.